# passing variable number of arguments to sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to pass variable number parameters to sql query. As an example:

```
select column1  
from Table    
where column2 in ( '0080','0010')    
group by column1    
having count(distinct column2) >= 2
```

In the where clause, 2 arguments `0080` and `0010` are used. But this number of arguments can vary based on the input from user. As an example it could be like this:

```
select column1  
from Table    
where column2 in ( '0080','0010', '0020', '0050', '0060')    
group by column1    
having count(distinct column2) >= 5
```

So, this number of arguments is not fixed and it will be passed by the user from an *`.xml`* file.

How can we pass a variable number of arguments to the query? As the number of arguments is not fixed and it can be changed from time to time, can we use an array or something similar?

Comment: is this a stored procedure or dynamic?

Comment: You need to build the query in some other language; likely the same language with which you now read that .XML .

Comment: This has been asked a number of times. It's not possible without modifying the query.

Comment: Let's assume it as a stored one

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try to load the arguments into a temporary table and use that in the where clause in a subquery. In particular if your argument list becomes very large, this is much more scalable.